# static or instance methods for dbHelper?

Tags: java, database, static, instance

I have following scenario, and a confusion to have instance method or static method for `dbhelper`?

- We have a dbhelper class which as name suggest help other classes to work with MySql db.
- The db helper class will be used by 2 independent module. 
  Java Webapp. 
  Windows based Java app
- Currently all the methods in dbhelper class are instance methods
  There are 8 methods in dbhelper class among which 3 will be common for webapp and windows app and rest only used by webapp.
- Windows app is kind of continuously running 24*7.
- Our confusion is such that if we keep methods as instance methods, then we have to crate object of `dbhelper` class and eventually will be always alive as used by windows app.
- What I see advantage of keeping methods as static is no object required.

**Note:**

I know how static and instance method works.

Google search do not help for this specific example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is too broad for a specific answer.  But I can answer with the kinds of things I'd be thinking about, in general.

First of all, if your static methods are going to save state in static class variables, that's not good practice.  If there's any state involved, you definitely want to make them instance methods, so that an object of that instance will be holding the state.

You mention that your methods are there to help work with a database.  How are they going to access the database?  If the database isn't passed as one of the method parameters, then that means the reference to the database has to be stored somewhere, and I think it's best if the dbhelper is an instance that stores a reference to the database (or a reference to some other object that can be used to retrieve the database object) as one of the instance fields.

So I'm going to assume that the methods take a database parameter, or a parameter to some other object that will give you the database object.  Given that, there are two things I'd think about when considering whether to make your methods static.

(1) What is the likelihood that the method will change because the requirements change?  If it's at all likely, then I'd definitely lean toward making the methods instance methods; in fact, I'd consider making "dbhelper" an abstract class or interface, and having different implementation classes implement the abstract methods in different ways when something changes.  That seems to me to be more flexible than just having one static class whose code has to change if the business logic changes.  It lets you switch back and forth, or even lets you switch the logic dynamically at run time.

(2) Will you want to mock the method for testing?  If your methods access a database, then you will probably want to provide a mock version of the method when unit-testing other classes that call the method, since you want to be able to test them without worrying about setting up the database access and everything.  This would also argue for making dbhelper abstract or interface, so that you can provide a mock implementation in addition to your real implementation.  (However, some testing platforms like JMockit will let you mock static methods.)

Those are the kinds of things that would lead me toward making the methods instance methods.  If you're sure that they don't apply, then it should be OK to make them static methods.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using static, make use of Singleton design approach for dbHelper class.

something like this,

```
public class MyDBHelper {

private static MyDBHelper instance;

private MyDBHelper(){}

public static MyDBHelper getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new MyDBHelper();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void addRow() {
 ........
    }

}
```

From other classes, you can access the methods like below

```
MyDBHelper.getInstance().addRow();
```

Answer (score 1):

1st : Make all methods of class `dbhelpe` `static` and load them when your application gets loaded by any web/application server.This task can be accomplished by `static block` .

2nd : try to implement `Singleton pattern` on your `dbhelp` class ,so that only one object of your class can be shared,this will not leads your application to create object many times,and your application will work faster.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, methods in one class used by multiple callers (web app and Windows app) suggests violation of [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), so you should be dividing the single DB helper into multiple classes.

Secondly, there are advantages and disadvantages of static and instance methods.

If you practice [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) or [DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), it discourages static methods as they are non-mockable (unless you use a framework like [Powermock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) which to me seems a bit hacky.)

If you only do end to end testing, its okay to use static methods.